# Hide free shipping for certain product category woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Not sure this question has been asked before.

In my online shop, I have set the free shipping for orders more than $150.

However, I do not want to include whiteboards for free shipping even though it costs more than $150.

So basically I want to exclude whiteboards from free shipping.

The issue I am facing is even I set the shipping charge for whiteboard class as $33, the free shipping option is visible (automatically checked) on the top of $33.

[image]

Thus I need to remove this free shipping option only for whiteboards.

I have another requirement which is shipping locations. I only need to ship the whiteboards to certain postcodes in my state (Queensland, Australia). Not to the whole state.

Any suggestions on how to perform the above 2 requirements?

I hope you understand my question. Please comment below if you have any queries. Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you need two distinct shipping classes. One for products that fit your free shipping for $150+ and one for whiteboards only. Then make sure that your products are properly assigned to the correct shipping class. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-shipping-classes

Comment: As Levidps suggessted you need shipping classes to define shipping rules based on products. I think the default Free Shipping method doesn't have this option. You can use Advanced Free Shipping plugin (free version) to achieve that functionality. https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-free-flat-shipping-woocommerce/